# How to group many timestamps only by one individual date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two different timestamps and one for when an account is created, and one for when they first use a product. If the first use of a product is less than 24 hours from when an account is created, it is assigned a 1 in a dummy variable column, if not, it is assigned a 0. I want to then group these by individual days, not each individual timestamp.

I have tried GROUP BY and then various combinations of `DATEADD`and`DATEDIFF`as well as creating a function to display dates between two days and nothing has worked.

```
SELECT data.ORIGINAL_TIMESTAMP AS "data_timestamp",
       data2.ORIGINAL_TIMESTAMP AS "data2_timestamp",
       CASE
           WHEN DATEDIFF(minute, data.ORIGINAL_TIMESTAMP, data2.ORIGINAL_TIMESTAMP) <=1440 THEN 1
           ELSE 0
       END AS "24_hour_dummy_variable",
       ((SUM("24_hour_dummy_variable")) OVER (
                                              ORDER BY data.ORIGINAL_TIMESTAMP ASC rows between 999 preceding AND current row)*100) AS "running_avg"
FROM data 
LEFT JOIN data2
  ON data.ACCOUNT = data2.ACCOUNT

  GROUP BY DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, org_created.ORIGINAL_TIMESTAMP), 0)
```

Invalid argument types for function `'DATE_DIFFTIMESTAMPINMONTHS'`

Comment: Please Show code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using multiple queries like this:

```
WITH table_a as 
(SELECT data.id id,
         CASE
         WHEN data.ORIGINAL_TIMESTAMP - data2.ORIGINAL_TIMESTAMP <=1 THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END dummy_variable
FROM data 
JOIN data2
ON data.ACCOUNT = data2.ACCOUNT)
Select sum(table_a.dummy_variable) agg, trunc(data.original_timestamp)
FROM data
JOIN table_a on table_a.id = data.id
GROUP BY trunc(data.original_timestamp)
```

This code is for OracleSQL but you can do the same in MySQL as well.

Comment: thank you! I was just wondering how the agg and trunc functions work in this case?

Comment: agg is not a function but just an alias for the aggregated result and the trunc function truncates the time part for the datetime in DB.